# Display facebook apprequests form inline on application page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Haven't really found any answers that give me quite what I need.

I have a page in an application that is designed to be part of a three-step process, one of which is to invite friends. I'd like to display the friend multi-select form inline on that page - so not using the modal popup, and not using the interstitial http://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&message=abc method (since that takes the user away from the branded page).

Is there any way to get that form into an application's page, inline? I naively tried using an iframe but that just gives me the "go to Facebook" auth error page inside the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered already here on another question (that was actually asking something totally different)

The solution is to combine [FB.XFBML.parse](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) with [serverFbml](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/serverFbml/) which will render Facebook's own form in your own pages as though it belonged there.

Comment: The documentation for the facebook api is probably more complicated than the api itself!